# Python logging help needed for newbie

Tags: python, logging

Help me understand please. I'm new in python. I'm writing WSGI app. And I want to turn loggining on. I do:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

then I want to print something in log:

```
logger.exception("Some exception...")
```

Where it all stores? Only in console output or there is a file somewhere on the server? If so, where I can find this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you have to specify the file yourself, e.g. with [logging.basicConfig()](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig):

```
logging.basicConfig(filename="/path/to/your/logfile.log")
```

Logging can be quite a complex matter sometimes, I'd suggest you read the [HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
import logging
logging.error("Error")  # Prints to console
```

This how to write a log to a file

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='Error.log',level=logging.ERROR)
logging.error('Error')
```

Opening the `Error.log` you will see

```
ERROR:root:Error
```

More info [here](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging.html)

Comment: Where does "And this, too" come from?

Comment: I would not log a message "Error" with level `WARNING` :)

Comment: Rakesh, I don't think that was what @Tichodroma was talking about. Your edit sets the logging level to `logging.ERROR`, which means nothing will get logged because a warning is less important than an error. Tichodroma's comment seems to refer to your calling `warning()` with a message consisting of `Error`. Indeed, in that case, you probably should call `error()` instead :)